# Why application crash for "failed to resume" when using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

My application need supporting user feedback through eMail. We prefer to use MFMailComposeViewController rather than url schema, because we need attaching some log files in the mail.
However application may crash for "failed to resume in time", when user act as follow steps.

```
1. Get into message editing view;
2. "Cancel-->Save Draft";
3. When saving draft, presh home button. Application will enter background state;
4. User launch application again, application will block in launch image. After few second, application will crash.
```

The device log said :

```
Jul  2 15:38:58 unknown SpringBoard[57] <Warning>: com.XXX failed to resume in time
Jul  2 15:38:58 unknown SpringBoard[57] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of XXX[461]...
Jul  2 15:38:59 unknown SpringBoard[57] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Jul  2 15:38:59 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.XXX[0x8c58]) Exited: Killed: 9
```

**Questions:
Why my application block during resume?

Why MFMailComposeViewController use so long time to save draft?

How can I walk around to avoiding crash?**

Crash Report:

```
Date/Time:       2012-07-03 09:25:40.222 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.XXX failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.720 (user 1.720, system 0.000), 17% CPU
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.009, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x35ca8010 0x35ca7000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x35ca8206 0x35ca7000 + 4614
2   AppSupport                    0x376c68c4 0x376b4000 + 75972
3   AppSupport                    0x376c52f0 0x376b4000 + 70384
4   AppSupport                    0x376c59a6 0x376b4000 + 72102
5   AppSupport                    0x376c3cfc 0x376b4000 + 64764
6   AppSupport                    0x376c3b8a 0x376b4000 + 64394
7   MessageUI                     0x305dea90 0x305d5000 + 39568
8   MessageUI                     0x306048b2 0x305d5000 + 194738
9   MessageUI                     0x305f3914 0x305d5000 + 125204
10  MessageUI                     0x305f2fa0 0x305d5000 + 122784
11  MessageUI                     0x306025ce 0x305d5000 + 185806
12  UIKit                         0x3727fcd4 0x37143000 + 1297620
13  CoreFoundation                0x33cf742e 0x33ce4000 + 78894
14  UIKit                         0x371619e4 0x37143000 + 125412
15  UIKit                         0x371619a0 0x37143000 + 125344
16  UIKit                         0x3716197e 0x37143000 + 125310
17  UIKit                         0x371616ee 0x37143000 + 124654
18  UIKit                         0x37162026 0x37143000 + 127014
19  UIKit                         0x37160508 0x37143000 + 120072
20  UIKit                         0x3715fefa 0x37143000 + 118522
21  UIKit                         0x371464e6 0x37143000 + 13542
22  UIKit                         0x37145d26 0x37143000 + 11558
23  GraphicsServices              0x30578dec 0x30574000 + 19948
24  CoreFoundation                0x33d7154c 0x33ce4000 + 578892
25  CoreFoundation                0x33d714ee 0x33ce4000 + 578798
26  CoreFoundation                0x33d7033c 0x33ce4000 + 574268
27  CoreFoundation                0x33cf34d6 0x33ce4000 + 62678
28  CoreFoundation                0x33cf339e 0x33ce4000 + 62366
29  GraphicsServices              0x30577fc6 0x30574000 + 16326
30  UIKit                         0x3717473c 0x37143000 + 202556
31  XXX                   0x00002d26 0x1000 + 7462
32  XXX                   0x00002ce4 0x1000 + 7396
```